# Text search in Google app store

Tags: google-app-engine, search, google-cloud-datastore

Our application is using `Google App Engine` and `DataStore` for the server side. 
We are storing Blogs model with name and description in the datastore.

We want to provide search feature for the description. We could not find correct way to do it.

Can anyone guide us the correct method to search blogs with specific description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [search service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview) (which is currently experimental).